# First-order language.

Tags: first-order-logic

In Elliot Mendelson's "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" there is a [definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piFco.jpg) of a first-order language $L$ which says, that it contains *denumerably* many individual variables. A first-order theory in the language $L$, by its [definition](https://imgur.com/8fSChTb), contain the same symbols as $L$.

As we know, the $\text{ZFC}$ set theory (as an example) is a first-order theory where we call those individual variables "sets". But then we have only countably many sets, since there are only countably many variables. This is definitely wrong. What do I miss?

Comment: Having denumerably infinite many individual variables is pretty much a convenient way to allow formulas (which are finite in a formal first-order theory) to have as many distinct variables as may be needed to carry out substitution, etc.  It does not limit how may objects may belong to a model of the theory.

Comment: @hardmath so I need only countably many variables to write all axioms. And I have much more sets since they are "anything that satisfies these axioms".

Comment: Indeed you often have only finitely many variables to write all axiom schemas of a formal first-order theory, and this does not essay against models of such a theory being infinite.  If one infinite model exists, the Lowenheim-Skolem theorems tell us there exists a model of any specified infinite cardinality.  The language of a formal first-order theory should have countably many  variables to allow arbitrary expression substitution in the axiom schemas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are variables and sets are sets, they belong to different worlds, the first ones are syntactic objects while the second ones are semantic. Even if you're interpreting your variables as denoting sets you don't need one variable for each set, so from the fact you have countably many variables in your language doesn't follow there are countably many sets

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the symbols we use in a logic language and the kinds of objects we try to symbolize with them, and we usually don't have a symbol for every object in our domain. For example, Peano arithmetic, which is our language for the natural numbers, has a symbol only for the number 0.